# Browsersync with VS and Gulp

Tags: sass, gulp

Hey Folks am stuck trying to do a browsersync /css/js inject when using an external URL.
I have visual studio code and gulp everything set up correctly not sure what setting am missing or have wrong.

Here is my gulp.js file

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
// Requires the gulp-sass plugin
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('sass', function(){
    return gulp.src('sass/**/*.scss')
      .pipe(sass()) // Converts Sass to CSS with gulp-sass
      .pipe(gulp.dest('css/'))
      .pipe(browserSync.stream());

  });


  gulp.task('watch',  ['browserSync', 'sass'], function(){
    gulp.watch('sass/**/*.scss', ['sass']); 
    // Reloads the browser whenever HTML or JS files change
  gulp.watch('*.html', browserSync.reload); 
  gulp.watch('js/**/*.js', browserSync.reload); 
  });


  var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
  gulp.task('browserSync', function() {
    browserSync.init({
      proxy: 'https://sustainability.dev.colostate.edu/',
      host: 'sustainability.dev.colostate.edu/',
      open: 'external',

    });
  })
```

Comment: You don't say what error(s) you have but does putting the line var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create(); at the top help?

Comment: Hey Mark, doesn't help. :) the error is that the page does not refresh nor inject the browser. I mean I can see in terminal that it's running the "refreshing browser" but nothing happens browser wise. Sass is compiling etc so am wondering if the url is wrong but don't know what is should be

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm having the same issue